# How to make JTextPane show hyphen/dash with the same width as an alphabet?

Tags: java, jtextpane

The "-" in my JTextPane is shorter than a letter or digit. This makes the multi line texts not aligned. Eg.

```
1234 1234 abcd
a--- 1--- a---
1234 1234 abcd
```

appears as

```
1234 1234 abcd
a-- 1-- abcd
1234 1234 abcd
```

Any trick to solve this?

Comment: Sorry, the format was removed as I post. Anyway, for example, in notepad++, 4 dashes has the same width as 4 "a", but in the JTextPane, 4 dashes has the width of 3 "a". That's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Font font = new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12);
```

This font set to the textpane seems has some effect.